# Get a child linegeometry from geometrygroup in c# (canvas) When it is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, geometry, mouse, shapes

I would like to know how to remove a `linegeometry` from a `geometrygroup` inside a:

```
void Window1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
```

When I try: `e.Source.GetType()` is equal to `typeof(Path)`, not to the `linegeometry`, so i cannot do a simple: `LineConnectors.Children.Remove(e.Source)`.

I have several lines Added as `linegeometry` children inside two different `geometrygroup` (`LineConnectors` and `LineConnectors2`) and what I'm trying to do is to introduce a button that delete the specific line that is the one that the client clicks after had clicked on the delete button.

Basically what is happening is that `e.Source` is the geometrygroup with all lines including the one that I would remove and not just its child (the linegeometry) which is the line that I need remove.

How is this possible? Thanks

Comment: Thanks. This were my first time so I didn't know how to do it well. I would like to remove this line from the 'LineConnectors.Children'